# Synchronising the CCLayer & UIView animation

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I have added a tableView as a subview to the **[[CCDirector sharedDirector]view]** over a **CCLayer**. Then I have animated the **CCLayer** & **tableView** separately With the following codes :

This Code moves the **CCLayer to the right & left**.

```
-(void)moveHomeScreenLayerWithIsAnimated:(BOOL)_isAnimationRight{

    if (!_isAnimationRight) {
        [mHomeLayer runAction:[CCSequence actionOne:[CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:0.0f]   two:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:0.4f position:ccp((size.width/4)*3, 0)]]];
    }
    else{
        [mHomeLayer runAction:[CCSequence actionOne:[CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:0.0f] two:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:0.4f position:ccp(0, 0)]]];
    }
}
```

And for **tableView's animation**:

```
-(void)ViewAnimationRight{

    [UIView cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self];
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4f];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];

    tableViewHome.frame = CGRectMake(size.width - size.width/4,topBar.contentSize.height, size.width, size.height);
    [tableViewHome setScrollEnabled:NO];

    [UIView commitAnimations ];
}

-(void)ViewAnimationLeft{
    [UIView cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self];
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4f];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];

    tableViewHome.frame = CGRectMake(0, topBar.contentSize.height, size.width, size.height);
    [tableViewHome setScrollEnabled:YES];

    [UIView commitAnimations ];
}
```

Both the CCLayer & tableView gets animated, but their animations are not synchronised. The animation duration times are not matching. Is there any other way around. Everyone's help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try and synchronize the calls to both the functions at the place of the calls. Make sure there is no heavy code in between the calls to add delays. That might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

first set 320 in x position of your uiview

```
//right to left animation
CGRect basketTopFrame = basketTop.frame;
basketTopFrame.origin.x = 0;
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{ basketTop.frame = basketTopFrame; } completion:^(BOOL finished){ 
}];

//left to right animation
CGRect napkinBottomFrame = basketTop.frame;
napkinBottomFrame.origin.x = 320;
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:0.0 options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{ basketTop.frame = napkinBottomFrame; } completion:^(BOOL finished) 
{
    /*done*/
}];
```

basketTop is an object of your uiview

Comment: I have tried implementing your code but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to reliably achieve synchroneous motion is to not use actions and ui animations. They just work too different.

Instead update the layer and view positions manually in a scheduled update method. Check the move action code on how to ensure a certain position is reached within a given time.